# Easy way to compute the area between $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=x^2\ln(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Is there an easy to compute the area between $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=x^2\ln(x)$ without refering to the [Lambert W-function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function)?

Comment: Why would you need the Lambert W-function?

Comment: how else would you do it? cause otherwise it is not that easy to see where both functions intersect

Comment: @Lipschitz Are you talking about a define integral? If so, then what are the integration limits?

Comment: it is given by the intersection points of both functions, so 0 and the other point which is somewhat hard to describe without using Lambert-W function.

Comment: I'm assuming you are referring to the intersection point?

Comment: yes, zero is the obvious one, but the other one is problematic

Comment: Would you rather have the limit in a different form, like an infinite series?

Comment: no, actually this is an excercise that I have found in a school book, so there is maybe a trick how one can do this. as I highly doubt that they understand much of this stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By letting $x_0$ be the positive point that satisfies $x_0 \log x_0 = 1$, we get that [the relevant integral equals a polynomial in $x_0$ (of degree $3$)](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%20x-x%5E2%20log%28x%29%20from%200%20to%20x_0). This is probably the simplest expression you can get for this value. Since $x_0 = W(1)^{-1}$, I would guess the answer to your question is "no".

Answer (score 0):

By looking at a figure we can assume that the functions intersects at some point $x_0$, which we will write as $x_0 = \exp(\Omega)$ for reasons that will become apparent later.

Again from figure we obtain that the enclosed area can be expressed as

$$ \begin{align} 
A & = \int_0^{e^{\Omega}} x - x^2 \log x\,\mathrm{d}x \\ 
  & = \frac{1}{2} e^{2 \Omega} - \frac{1}{3} \Omega e^{3\Omega} + \frac{1}{9} e^{3 \Omega} 
\end{align} $$

Now if we just could find $\Omega$ we would be done. But luckilly $\Omega$ is a "well" know constant!

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omega_constant

Using some exponent rules $a^b a^b= a^{2b}$, and that $1 = \Omega \exp(\Omega)$,
we can rewrite the area as

$$ A = \frac{1}{6} e^{2W} + \frac{1}{9} e^{3W} $$

For example by using the recurrence relation

$$ \Omega_{n+1} = \frac{1 + \Omega_n}{1 + e^{\Omega_n}} $$

With the initial estimate of $\log 2$. We get that

$$ \Omega \approx \frac{1 + \log 2}{3}$$

Which is just $0.0027$ from the real value, replacing $\Omega$ with this expression the area can be rewritten as

$$ A = \frac{1}{6} 2^{2/3} e^{2/3} + \frac{2e}{9} \approx 1.1272$$

Which is quite close to the actuall value.